# Typescript assignment causes compilation error

Tags: typescript

Typescript is giving me a compilation error with the following code:

```
console.log('YHISTORY:login: data = '+data);
let theData = JSON.parse(data);
console.log('YHISTORY:login: theData = '+JSON.stringify(theData));
```

It complains when compiling the second line as follows:

`Error TS2345: Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'`

When I run this code the first line generates this console output:

```
YHISTORY:login: data = {"key":"4ba9f2eec3a59e76799a728f0dcda831b7f1fb66"}
```

The third line does not produce any console output. The following error is generated:

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this is null
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is not about assignment, it's about calling `JSON.parse()` function. Error looks like your `data` variable is already an object, when `string` is expected as function argument.

You can reproduce this error with this example:

```
var data = {};
JSON.parse(data);
```

Comment: The typeof data is string.

Comment: Then there is not enough information for suggestion. In theory `Error TS2345` can be incorrect while using incorrect `.d.ts` typescript definitions. It can be declared as object, but javascript still returns `string`. What about exception it looks like not aligned to this lines of code. I can suggest some scoping problems somewhere inside Promise handling, as an example using `function(){}` notation without binding `this`.

Comment: The problem tuned out to be using 

.then(function(data) {

rather than 

.then((data:any)=>{ 

in the promise handler